# PayPal as payment gateway on my marketplace website

Tags: paypal

I have a website where my users can create custom pages to sell virtual things. At the moment, the only payment gateway their buyers can use is Stripe since it's the only my website currently supports. I would like to add PayPal support, so my sellers can enter their PayPal email, then buyers can purchase goods using PayPal.

I looked into PayPal's API, and the only thing I could really find was the checkout API for commerce. I'm not interested in having any of that fancy API, or needing to have sellers enter API key(s). I simply want sellers to enter their PayPal email, and boom - done. I also do not want to have to get a verified business on PayPal if possible since I still need to do a lot of work before submitting my application for approval from PayPal.

**Example:**

Joe creates a page on my website to sell pictures. He wants to add PayPal support, so he goes to my website's dashboard, enters his PayPal email, and then clicks confirm. Now his buyers can purchase his pictures using PayPal.

Where should I be looking for information on this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a PayPal business account. Follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

To send the funds to another account, [specify a payee](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/) in the order creation request.